# Uncaught ReferenceError: Mini is not defined at (index):993 - magento 2 store

Tags: javascript, error, google-analytics, chrome-browser

How do i trace and fix this error for my magento 2 store?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Mini is not defined at (index):993
```

i can not find the below code anywhere in my magento admin. it is not in header, footer, script sections, nor google api for analytics is enabled.

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
Mini// <![CDATA[
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
// ]]></script>
</p>
```

Comment: what did you do before this error?

Comment: i'm not quite remember, it's been there for awhile, does not affect anything though.

Comment: are you on a live production mode? try to enable developer mode and check

Comment: i changed to dev mode, but still the same error. is there a log file to trace it from?

Comment: yeah just go to var/report or var/log/excepion or debug